# Show that Countable complete metric space has infinitely many isolated points

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

My Approch:
If $X$ is countable complete metric space, it has atleast one isolated point $x$ by Baire Category Theorem.
Consider, $X_1$= $X\setminus \{x\}$
Since,$x$ is isolated point of $X$, hence $X_1$ is also complete & countable. By similar argument we can consider $X_2$ & so on.

Is this correct approach to conclude $X$ has infinitely many isolated points.

Comment: It is correct, but countable does not always mean countably infinite. So you should start with a countably infinite metric space.